# GHUnit for Integration Testing iOS Network functions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, integration-testing

I have an iOS application (but this is just as applicable to an OS X app) that has async network access functions. Using GHUnit and without manually doing inner run loops, or synchronization of async operations, is it possible have a test method run an async operation and verify the results AFTER the async operation is complete.

I don't see anything in GHUnit to allow this but I might be blind. I do know of people who do this with inner run loops, but I have a bunch of integration tests and don't want to set this up for each test.

Comment: I don't use GHUnit, but is [this blog entry](http://blog.moonshine-project.com/en/2009/11/22/asynchronous-unit-testing-with-ghunit-and-nsinvocation/) handy at all?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not exactly what I'm looking for but I think I'll be able to build something based on their work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just stumbled into the same problem (and blog post, which contains some key pieces filtered due to comparison operators).

You're looking for [`GHAsyncTestCase`](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/interface_g_h_async_test_case.html) within GHUnit. The example in the description does a better job than I'd be able to do.

Comment: I hadn't looked at GHAsyncTestCase and now that you point it out, I think that might solve my problem entirely. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The GHUnit async example shows you how to setup, but does not run any tests after the async operation is completed.

The trick to do it is to call the asserts AFTER `waitForStatus`.

An example here: http://samwize.com/2012/11/25/create-async-test-with-ghunit/